# Tell proc_entry->write_proc to use an ioctl with an argument?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, kernel-module, ioctl

I've seen some sample code that does this:

```
proc_entry->read_proc = module_read;
proc_entry->write_proc = module_write;
```

However, in my module, I've used ioctls instead of the read and write. Here is my ioctl function prototype:

```
int mytimer_ioctl(struct inode *inode, struct file *file, unsigned int fcn, unsigned long args)
```

For read, my "fcn" is IOCTL_GET_TIMER, and for write, my "fcn" is IOCTL_SET_TIMER.

Anyway to do something like this:

```
proc_entry->read_proc = module_ioctl(IOCTL_GET_TIMER);
proc_entry->write_proc = module_ioctl(IOCTL_SET_TIMER);
```

But not pass in the "args" argument?

Or maybe the easier way is to just write the module_read and module_write function, and have those call the ioctl?

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do this. Just implement forwarding functions.

Comment: Thanks, I will work on that... However, I'm not sure how I can forward them anymore since the ioctl call requires *inode and *file inputs also... What would I do for that?

Comment: read and write calls take "struct file* pfil", don't they? Then I believe it's "filp->f_dentry->d_inode".